# How can i change nearby to radar search service on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google nearbySearch service on my website and i am trying to change it to radarSearch. 
However when i am changing the nearbySearch to radarSearch i am getting no results!

Here is my code:

```
function placesCall()
{
cleanPlacesArray();

var request = 
{
    location: marker.getPosition(),
    radius: 3000,  
    types: places
};
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, 
    function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
            {
                createPlaceMarker(results[i]);
            }
        };

    })
}
```

I already tried this aproach but doesnt work:

```
service.radarSearch(request, 
function callback(results, status) 
{
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) 
{

  for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
    createMarker(result);
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: What is `createMarker`?  Did you look at [the example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests) ([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search))?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you have to change, `radarSearch` and `nearbySearch` accept the same arguments.

When you didn't get the expected result you probably need to change `createMarker`.

The informations  for places returned by a `radarSearch` are  less detailed, I guess the issue is that you try to access a property in `createMarker` that is available in a `nearbySearch`, but not in a `radarSearch`.

The properties available when running a `radarSearch` are:

- geometry
- place_id
- reference
- html_attributions